# When using underscores, should they be reserved to junction tables?

Tags: database-design

Say you have the following tables

- company (contains companies)
- industry (contains industries)
- company_type (contains company types, e.g., Public, Private)
- company_status (contains company statuses, e.g., Acquired, Operating)
- company_industry (junction table between company and industry)

Using an underscore in the company_type and company_status tables makes it a bit difficult to easily glance at the database and tell which tables are junction tables.

Should underscores be reserved for junction tables? If so, how do you deal with a table like company_type? Simply naming it 'type' is non-descriptive, and is a SQL reserved keyword. As well, what if you have school types and you want to keep them separate from company types? I.e., school_type table and company_type table.

As an aside: I'm looking for a good resource on naming in database design. It's the one thing troubling me more than anything else.

Comment: Depends on your database. You should use snake_case for all identifiers in PostgreSQL. Which means that if you want to be cross-database compatible, you should use snake_case for all identifiers in all databases

Comment: Name your tables so that the names make sense in queries. Use the closest thing to your organization's natural business language that is practical.  An intersection between `USER` and `ROLE` should be `ROLE_MEMBER` not `USER_ROLE`.  _Sometimes_ slamming the two referenced table names together with an underscore is the best you can do, but I almost always feel like I've failed if I resort to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use underscore in that way, try using CamelCase the rest of the time.

Then you'd have `CompanyType` , and if a company could have many types, you could have a junction table called `Company_CompanyType`

Comment: Oy vey! Going with CamelCase would mean an entire redesign of my database schema. Though, with the amount of tables it may be worth it, since I am trying to make it easy to look at the tables and easily tell what everything does. I am doing a redesign, and trying to figure out what the table 'type' contained just by looking at the database was nearly impossible. OK, good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise, use something else instead of an underscore for junction tables.

Comment: According to the SQL standard `CompanyType` will be stored as `COMPANYTYPE` because all non-quoted identifiers must be converted to uppercase. Therefore it's better to use "snake case": `COMPANY_TYPE`

Comment: I decided to go with _to_ in my junction tables. So, e.g., company_to_industry.

Comment: CamelCase? Not when using a RDBMS. Everything should be uppercase, I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name on that. Case sensitivity shouldn't come into it.

Comment: I was simply offering an alternative based on his description, considering he wasn't going for allcaps, and was keen to use an underscore in that way...